# How to run a function when a class var is edited

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, pdo

I've done recently an account system and i want to do it again properly in OOP. I've almost finished the class *usr* but i want (when the user change the value of "avatarURL") to run a little function to update the value in the database.
Something like:

```
class usr{
  public $username, $mail, $password // [...]

  function __construct($username){
  // I initialize the mail, password, avatar URL and the Session
  }

  function(){ /* To run if $this->avatarURL is edited */
    // Check if is correct value first and then something like :
    $bdd= new PDO(...);
    $sql = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE `avatarURL` IN `accounts` WHERE `username`=?');
    $sql->execute(array(*newValue*));
  }
}
```

I'm almost sure that's possible i just don't know how and i haven't found anything helpful on my Google so...

Comment: Make the properties private, and require the caller to use a `setAvatarURL()` method.

Comment: I'm new in OOP and it's exactly what I want to do (I've already done that in other languages like C++ or ...) but I don't exactly know how :s  Do you have a link or just the func to use ?

Comment: `private $avatarURL;` and `public function setAvatarURL() { ...}`

Comment: It's almost exactly the same as C++.

Comment: Oh ok I just didn't understand what you meant first, yeah it's a good idea and I really feal idiot right now x) I have already done many function like that but I felt with this var it should be different, don't know why :p